# Bash: Using Array Parameter Expansion to Include Items Matching Pattern

Tags: macos, bash, pattern-matching

I would like to use bash parameter expansion on an array to *include* items matching a given pattern, rather than to *exclude* them.

Here's an example excluding the items matching `ba*`:

```
ar=( foo bar baz qux )
for i in ${ar[@]##ba*}; do
    echo "$i"
done

# foo
# qux
```

That's all well and good, but in this case I'd actually like to include only the items matching `ba*`.

Here's what I've tried, and frankly, I'm not quite sure how to interpret the results:

```
ar=( foo bar baz qux )
#shopt -s extglob  # seems to have no effect either way
for i in ${ar[@]##!(ba*)}; do
    echo "$i"
done

# ar
# az
```

It looks like I'm in this case I'm getting the right items, but their values have been munged.

Here's my current working solution:

```
ar=( foo bar baz qux )
for i in ${ar[@]}; do
    if [[ "$i" =~ ba* ]]; then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done

# bar
# baz
```

I am using Mac OSX and have tested this with Mac bundled bash 3.2.51 as well as Homebrew installed bash 4.2.45.

Thanks!

**Edit**

@casc (rightly) suggests below to just re-append the removed 'b' from the matches, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

My actual use case would be more like including items that match `*ba*`, not just `ba*`.  The point is that I don't necessarily know the full string, just that it will definitely have the pattern `ba*` somewhere.  This may be a better example:

```
ar=( foo zoobar waybaz qux )
for i in ${ar[@]}; do
    if [[ "$i" =~ ba* ]]; then
        # do something with $i
    fi
done

# zoobar
# waybaz
```

Answer (score 1):

From each element of the array, you are removing the longest prefix that does not match `ba*`.

1. For `foo` and `qua`, the entire string does not match.
2. For `bar` and `baz`, `b` does not match `ba*`, but `ba` does, so only `b` is removed.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  So do you know if there's a way to do what I want with parameter expansion?  It seems like it may not be possible with bash.  I've seen something like what I want accomplished with zsh: `for i in ${(M)ar:#ba*}`, which is I guess where I got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply prepend the chopped-off `b` again?

```
(
shopt -s extglob
ar=( foo bar baz qux )
for i in ${ar[@]/#!(ba*)}; do
   echo "b${i}"
done
)

# ... or ...

(
export IFS=""
ar=( foo bar baz qux )
ar=( ${ar[@]/#!(ba*)} )
ar=( ${ar[@]/#/b} )
echo ${!ar[*]}
printf '%s\n' "${ar[@]}"
)
```

Further alternatives include:

```
ar=( foo bar baz qux )
printf '%s\n' "${ar[@]}" "${ar[@]##ba*}" | sort | uniq -u
printf '%s\n' "${ar[@]}" "${ar[@]/#ba*}" | sort | uniq -u


# alternative to current working solution 
(
array=( foo bar baz qux )
for item in "${ar[@]}"; do
   case "$item" in
      ba*) echo "$item";;
        *) :;;
   esac
done
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The first two solutions rely on knowing all of the characters that were removed, so they don't work well if I try to replace `ba*` with `*ba*`.  The last three solutions work with a wildcard at the beginning, but the `printf`s don't give me much flexibility.  The last solution gives the best of both worlds but switch syntax is so ugly in shell -- it seems like a lateral move compared to my working solution.  

Out of curiosity, what are your paren blocks for?  Does this scope local variables?